# Is there a reliable way to convert unzoned datetime into UNIX time_t?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, timezone

I need to convert a database column in a (MSSQL) database table into UNIX time_t. The problem is that this column does not have a timezone and some dates are from GMT (+0000) and some from BST (+0100). I am working on UK times.

Is there a reliable way to convert unzoned datetime into UNIX time_t? I'm currently using

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01',event_time)
```

But this seems to be subject to the *current* timezone, not that applicable to the date.

I don't mind if I do the conversion in SQL or code. I'm working in Perl.

Comment: How do you currently tell which rows are GMT/UTC and BST?

Comment: They system doesn't. Hence my question.

Comment: How is this column being populated?

Comment: If you can't tell the difference between the timezones, how is your program going to be able to?

Comment: The underlying problem seems to be that the above DATEDIFF used the current time offset, rather than the time offset appropriate for event_time. Possibly fixable by going deep into SQL Server admin documentation (and bound to break when DB gets shifted to some new server etc), safer to handle it in code using hobbs code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that the times are BST in summer and GMT in winter then there *is* a timezone implicit in the column, and it's not "two different timezones", it's one timezone, called `Europe/London` in the Olson DB or `GMT0BST,M3.5.0/1,M10.5.0/2` in POSIX TZ format. You should easily be able to convert these times using the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) module or even clever use of the POSIX functions, except for the ambiguous hour around the fall transition, which can't be resolved unless you store an indication of whether BST was or was not in effect at the time.

Example using `DateTime`:

```
use DateTime::Format::MSSQL;
# In reality you would get this from the DB.
my $input = "2009-11-30 16:13:18.123";
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MSSQL->parse_datetime($input);
$dt->set_time_zone("Europe/London");
print "Unix time is ", $dt->epoch, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. That's reassuring to know it can be solved, but not an actual solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out in the morning.

Comment: Confirmed. The world is once more safe! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL 2008 there is a new date time type: [`datetimeoffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) that *does* retaint timezone info and thus can be used to susbtract diff from Unix epoch. But this requires upgrade to SQL 2008, revisiting your schema and changing the column type and updating retroactively all existing data to set the proper timezone.

If you cannot upgrade to SQL 2008 then I recommend storing your date time info as UDT always, which implies convert it in the client first before inserting it in the DB. Displaying the data to the user in the appopiate local time should be, again, done in the client.

Answer (score 0):

A UNIX timestamp is UTC without daylight savings time.  So if you can't tell if a date is GMT or BST, you can't convert it to a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: You're right, I was assuming BST was a time zone.  Apparently it's just summer time.  hobbs' answer should be all you need

Comment: Ah, as usual the mistake is in the question. I didn't mean timezone, but rather time offset. Thanks.